# Nuclear Fusion using magnetic fields

Tags: nuclear-physics, atomic-physics

I was wondering if you could use a very strong magnetic field to produce nuclear fusion. The basic idea is a spherical cavity containing Deuterium (and possibly tritium) nuclei whose walls will be electromagnets whose fields slowly increase in strength and will repel the nuclei and thus the ball of deuterium nuclei inside becomes smaller and smaller until finally the nuclei are close enough to fuse, could this work? If not why?

Comment: What would this field look like? Keep in mind that magnetic field is solenoidal and it does not "repel" a charge but in general it makes it spiral (see Lorentz force).

Comment: There's a proposal by a researcher named Slough to achieve fusion by using magnetic fields to compress a shell of lithium, compressing the D-T fuel contained therein.  The field doesn't directly compress the fuel, but magnetic fields do the compressing.  It's somewhat similar to your idea.

Comment: Pinch based fusion apparatus are among the oldest in the book. The research is still going on, but so far none of the machine configurations I am aware of has shown practical potential. Magnetic confinement is more realistic with Stellarator and Tokamak designs, even though Stellarators have turned out to be hellishly complex to manufacture with conventional machining methods. Curiously, Stellarators are a rare example of an application for which 3d printing could turn out to be the key to making them cheap enough to be competitive with Tokamaks.